# Does canvas tag support in asp.net, if no which tag should i use intead of this 

Tags: asp.net

I am working on asp.net , I am using  tag and using this in javascript

```
             window.onload = function () {
            // creating canvas objects
            canvas = document.getElementById('slideshow');
            ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
             }
```

but nothing is working on asp.net . this jquery is using for cube slide of images.

```
<canvas id="slideshow" width="880" height="400"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

The canvas tag is not supported by a framework but rather by a browser. Use IE9+/FF3.6+/Chrome in order to get your canvas working properly. The ASP.NET framework has nothing to do with this and your script should be working perfectly fine in a browser supporting HTML5 elements.

Comment: You might still be able to add runat="server" and have it wrapped as a HtmlGenericControl or some such.

Answer (score 0):

it's not supported you can use caneva in WPF as container, try with div control

try with this code

```
<div id="slideshow" width="880" height="400"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Canvas tag works on browser so don't worry if asp.net supports it or not. Just use it.